# Efficient way to optimise a Scala code to read large file that doesn't fit in memory

Tags: scala, optimization, file-io

## Problem Statement Below,

We have a large log file which stores user interactions with an application. The entries in the log file follow the following schema: {userId, timestamp, actionType} where actionType is one of two possible values: [open, close]

## Constraints:

1. The log file is too big to fit in memory on one machine. Also assume that the aggregated data doesn’t fit into memory.
2. Code has to be able to run on a single machine.
3. Should not use an out-of-the box implementation of mapreduce or 3rd party database; don’t assume we have a Hadoop or Spark or other distributed computing framework.
4. There can be multiple entries of each actionType for each user, and there might be missing entries in the log file. So a user might be missing a close record between two open records or vice versa.
5. Timestamps will come in strictly ascending order.

For this problem, we need to implement a class/classes that computes the average time spent by each user between open and close. Keep in mind that there are missing entries for some users, so we will have to make a choice about how to handle these entries when making our calculations. Code should follow a consistent policy with regards to how we make that choice.

The desired output for the solution should be [{userId, timeSpent},….] for all the users in the log file.

Sample log file (comma-separated, text file)

```
1,1435456566,open 
2,1435457643,open 
3,1435458912,open 
1,1435459567,close 
4,1435460345,open 
1,1435461234,open 
2,1435462567,close 
1,1435463456,open 
3,1435464398,close 
4,1435465122,close 
1,1435466775,close
```

## Approach

Below is the code I've written in Python & Scala, which seems to be not efficient and upto the expectations of the scenario given, I'd like to feedback from community of developers in this forum how better we could optimise this code as per given scenario.

### Scala implementation

```scala
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.{Scanner, Map, LinkedList}
import java.lang.Long
import scala.collection.mutable

object UserMetrics extends App {
  if (args.length == 0) {
    println("Please provide input data file name for processing")
  } 
  val userMetrics = new UserMetrics()
  userMetrics.readInputFile(args(0),if (args.length == 1) 600000 else args(1).toInt)
}

case class UserInfo(userId: Integer, prevTimeStamp: Long, prevStatus: String, timeSpent: Long, occurence: Integer)

class UserMetrics {

  val usermap = mutable.Map[Integer, LinkedList[UserInfo]]()

  def readInputFile(stArr:String, timeOut: Int) {
    var inputStream: FileInputStream = null
    var sc: Scanner = null
    try {
      inputStream = new FileInputStream(stArr);
      sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        val line: String = sc.nextLine();
        processInput(line, timeOut)
      }
      
      for ((key: Integer, userLs: LinkedList[UserInfo]) <- usermap) {
        val userInfo:UserInfo = userLs.get(0)
        val timespent = if (userInfo.occurence>0) userInfo.timeSpent/userInfo.occurence else 0
        println("{" + key +","+timespent + "}")
      }

      if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
      }
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
      }
      if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
      }
    }
  }

  def processInput(line: String, timeOut: Int) {
    val strSp = line.split(",")

    val userId: Integer = Integer.parseInt(strSp(0))
    val curTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(strSp(1))
    val status = strSp(2)
    val uInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo(userId, curTimeStamp, status, 0, 0)
    val emptyUserInfo: LinkedList[UserInfo] = new LinkedList[UserInfo]()

    val lsUserInfo: LinkedList[UserInfo] = usermap.getOrElse(userId, emptyUserInfo)

    if (lsUserInfo != null && lsUserInfo.size() > 0) {
      val lastUserInfo: UserInfo = lsUserInfo.get(lsUserInfo.size() - 1)
      val prevTimeStamp: Long = lastUserInfo.prevTimeStamp
      val prevStatus: String = lastUserInfo.prevStatus
      
      if (prevStatus.equals("open")) {
        if (status.equals(lastUserInfo.prevStatus)) {
           val timeSelector = if ((curTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp) > timeOut) timeOut else curTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp
           val timeDiff = lastUserInfo.timeSpent + timeSelector
          lsUserInfo.remove()
          lsUserInfo.add(UserInfo(userId, curTimeStamp, status, timeDiff, lastUserInfo.occurence + 1))
        } else if(!status.equals(lastUserInfo.prevStatus)){
          val timeDiff = lastUserInfo.timeSpent + curTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp
          lsUserInfo.remove()
          lsUserInfo.add(UserInfo(userId, curTimeStamp, status, timeDiff, lastUserInfo.occurence + 1))
        }
      } else if(prevStatus.equals("close")) {
        if (status.equals(lastUserInfo.prevStatus)) {
          lsUserInfo.remove()
          val timeSelector = if ((curTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp) > timeOut) timeOut else curTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp
          lsUserInfo.add(UserInfo(userId, curTimeStamp, status, lastUserInfo.timeSpent + timeSelector, lastUserInfo.occurence+1))
        }else if(!status.equals(lastUserInfo.prevStatus))
          {     
          lsUserInfo.remove()
          lsUserInfo.add(UserInfo(userId, curTimeStamp, status, lastUserInfo.timeSpent, lastUserInfo.occurence))
        }
      }
    }else if(lsUserInfo.size()==0){
      lsUserInfo.add(uInfo)
    }
    usermap.put(userId, lsUserInfo)
  }

}
```

### Python Implementation

```py
import sys

def fileBlockStream(fp, number_of_blocks, block):
    #A generator that splits a file into blocks and iterates over the lines of one of the blocks.
 
    assert 0 <= block and block < number_of_blocks #Assertions to validate number of blocks given
    assert 0 < number_of_blocks
 
    fp.seek(0,2) #seek to end of file to compute block size
    file_size = fp.tell() 
 
    ini = file_size * block / number_of_blocks #compute start & end point of file block
    end = file_size * (1 + block) / number_of_blocks
 
    if ini <= 0:
        fp.seek(0)
    else:
        fp.seek(ini-1)
        fp.readline()
 
    while fp.tell() < end:
        yield fp.readline() #iterate over lines of the particular chunk or block

def computeResultDS(chunk,avgTimeSpentDict,defaultTimeOut):
    countPos,totTmPos,openTmPos,closeTmPos,nextEventPos = 0,1,2,3,4
    for rows in chunk.splitlines():
        if len(rows.split(",")) != 3:
            continue
        userKeyID = rows.split(",")[0]
        try:
            curTimeStamp = int(rows.split(",")[1])
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Timestamp for ID:" + str(userKeyID))
            continue
        curEvent = rows.split(",")[2]
        if userKeyID in avgTimeSpentDict.keys() and avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos]==1 and curEvent == "close": 
        #Check if already existing userID with expected Close event 0 - Open; 1 - Close
        #Array value within dictionary stores [No. of pair events, total time spent (Close tm-Open tm), Last Open Tm, Last Close Tm, Next expected Event]
            curTotalTime = curTimeStamp - avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][openTmPos]
            totalTime = curTotalTime + avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos]
            eventCount = avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] + 1
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] = eventCount
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos] = totalTime
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][closeTmPos] = curTimeStamp
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos] = 0 #Change next expected event to Open
        
        elif userKeyID in avgTimeSpentDict.keys() and avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos]==0 and curEvent == "open":
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][openTmPos] = curTimeStamp
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos] = 1 #Change next expected event to Close
        
        elif userKeyID in avgTimeSpentDict.keys() and avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos]==1 and curEvent == "open":
            curTotalTime,closeTime = missingHandler(defaultTimeOut,avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][openTmPos],curTimeStamp)
            totalTime = curTotalTime + avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos]
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos]=totalTime
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][closeTmPos]=closeTime
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][openTmPos]=curTimeStamp
            eventCount = avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] + 1
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] = eventCount          

        elif userKeyID in avgTimeSpentDict.keys() and avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][nextEventPos]==0 and curEvent == "close": 
            curTotalTime,openTime = missingHandler(defaultTimeOut,avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][closeTmPos],curTimeStamp)
            totalTime = curTotalTime + avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos]
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][totTmPos]=totalTime
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][openTmPos]=openTime
            eventCount = avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] + 1
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID][countPos] = eventCount

        elif curEvent == "open":
            #Initialize userid with Open event
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID] = [0,0,curTimeStamp,0,1]
        
        elif curEvent == "close":
            #Initialize userid with missing handler function since there is no Open event for this User
            totaltime,OpenTime = missingHandler(defaultTimeOut,0,curTimeStamp)
            avgTimeSpentDict[userKeyID] = [1,totaltime,OpenTime,curTimeStamp,0]

def missingHandler(defaultTimeOut,curTimeVal,lastTimeVal):
    if lastTimeVal - curTimeVal > defaultTimeOut:
        return defaultTimeOut,curTimeVal
    else:
        return lastTimeVal - curTimeVal,curTimeVal

def computeAvg(avgTimeSpentDict,defaultTimeOut):
    resDict = {}
    for k,v in avgTimeSpentDict.iteritems():
        if v[0] == 0:
            resDict[k] = 0
        else:
            resDict[k] = v[1]/v[0]
    return resDict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    avgTimeSpentDict = {}
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Please provide input data file name for processing")
        sys.exit(1)
        
    fileObj = open(sys.argv[1])
    number_of_chunks = 4 if len(sys.argv) < 3 else int(sys.argv[2])
    defaultTimeOut = 60000 if len(sys.argv) < 4 else int(sys.argv[3])
    for chunk_number in range(number_of_chunks):
        for chunk in fileBlockStream(fileObj, number_of_chunks, chunk_number):
            computeResultDS(chunk, avgTimeSpentDict, defaultTimeOut)
    print (computeAvg(avgTimeSpentDict,defaultTimeOut))
    avgTimeSpentDict.clear() #Nullify dictionary 
    fileObj.close #Close the file object
```

Both program above gives desired output, but efficiency is what matters for this particular scenario. Let me know if you've anything better or any suggestions on existing implementation.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this sort of questions

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is iterator usage. I'm not going to re-write your code, but the trick here is likely to be using an `iterator`. Fortunately Scala provides decent out of the box tooling for the job.

```
import scala.io.Source
object ReadBigFiles {
  def read(fileName: String): Unit = {
    val lines: Iterator[String] = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines
    // now you get iterator semantics for the file line traversal
    // that means you can only go through the lines once, but you don't incur a penalty on heap usage
  }
}
```

For your use case, you seem to require a `lastUser`, so you're dealing with groups of 2 entries. I think you you have two choices, either go for `iterator.sliding(2)`, which will produce iterators for every pair, or simply add recursion to the mix using options.

```
def navigate(source: Iterator[String], last: Option[User]): ResultType = {
  if (source.hasNext) {
    val current = source.next()
    last match {
      case Some(existing) => // compare with previous user etc
      case None => navigate(source, Some(current))
    }
  } else {
    // exit recursion, return result
  }
}
```

You can avoid all the code you've written to read the file and so on. If you need to count occurrences, simply build a `Map` inside your recursion, and increment the occurrences at every step based on your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this could be very basic question, but I want to understand clearly. I couldn't quite understand when you say lastUser? I need to return avg time usage for all users & log entries for these users are in ascending order based on timestamp, so pairs (Open/Close Entry Per user) could be far away from each other. Writing this in a recursion won't take a lot of memory?

Comment: Build a map with averages by user id then, and compute them on a rolling basis, that's pretty easy to do. You don't care about the distance between pairs, that `lastUser` was just an example, i didn't really spend time the time trying to understand your business logic because it doesn't change the approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
from queue import LifoQueue, Queue

def averageTime() -> float:

   logs = {}
   records = Queue()

   with open("log.txt") as fp:
       lines = fp.readlines()   
       for line in lines:
           if line[0] not in logs:
               logs[line[0]] = LifoQueue()
               logs[line[0]].put((line[1], line[2]))
           else:
               logs[line[0]].put((line[1], line[2]))

   for k in logs:
       somme = 0
       count = 0
       while not logs[k].empty():
           l = logs[k].get()
           somme = (somme + l[0]) if l[1] == "open" else (somme - l[0])
           count = count + 1
       records.put([k, somme, count//2])

   while not records.empty():
       record = records.get()
       print(f"UserId={record[0]} Avg={record[1]/record[2]}")
```